# Código para gerar beep contínuo

Tags: python

O código abaixo faz o seguinte, ele lê um arquivo de log em tempo real e toda vez que na linha do código tiver a letra **N** é emitido um beep do windows.

A principio esse código está funcionando.

Pra entender oq estou fazendo, eu acesso uma máquina via putty, então eu gravo um log da sessão.

Nessa maquina existem vários sensores ligados, então quando um sensor é acionado na tela ele muda o status para ON, logo, quando desaciona OFF.

O código funciona, toda vez que o status fica ON bipa.

Toda vez que ele muda o status é incluso uma linha no log, por ser um log da sessão do putty.

Então se eu fico brincando de "liga-desliga" o beep acompanha.

Porém eu gostaria que se o ultimo status, ou seja, se ultima linha lida for com o status ON o beep ficasse ativo. Até q entre uma linha nova no arquivo com FF(de OFF).

To apanhando nessa parte, rs.. tentei inverter o IF pra comparar FF na condição, tentei usar While.. mas o beep dura somente o tempo que foi programado.

Alguém se habilita?

```
import time
import winsound

def monitorar(path):
with open(path, 'r') as arq:
    while True:
        nova_linha = arq.readline()
        nova_linha = nova_linha.replace('\n', '')
        if 'N' in nova_linha:
            yield nova_linha
            frequency = 2500  # Set Frequency To 2500 Hertz
            duration = 1000  # Set Duration To 1000 ms == 1 second
            winsound.Beep(2500, 1000)
        else:
            time.sleep(0.0)

caminho_arquivo = 'C:/loop/putty.log'
for idx, linha in enumerate(monitorar(caminho_arquivo)):
print("{:5d}: {}".format(idx, linha))
```

Comment: Esse `with` e tudo que está abaixo dele até o `time.sleep(0.0)` não deveria estar identado com mais 4 caracteres?

Comment: Não entendi, só sei q se vc copiar e colar esse codigo do jeito que está funciona rs

Comment: humm  já resolveu o seu problema ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A forma mais prática de manter o bipe tocando usando `winsound`, consiste em separar a parte que checa a condição lógica da parte que faz o som:

```
import time
import winsound

def monitorar(path):
    duration = 1000
    frequency = 2500
    ligado = False
    with open(path, 'r') as arq:
        while True:
            nova_linha = arq.readline()
            while nova_linha: 
            #Isto para quando nova_linha == '', um valor Falso
            #isto é - quando não há mais linhas para serem lidas
                if 'N' in nova_linha:
                   ligado = True
                elif 'FF' in nova_linha:
                   ligado = False
                yield nova_linha
                nova_linha = arq.readline()
            if ligado:
                winsound.Beep(2500, 1000)

caminho_arquivo = 'C:/loop/putty.log'
for idx, linha in enumerate(monitorar(caminho_arquivo)):
    print("{:5d}: {}".format(idx, linha))
```

Infelizmente, o `winsound.Beep` trava a execução ao tocar o som, e portanto caso o sensor esteja ligado e depois seja desligado, o bipe continua soando até a duração do último bipe. Outro aspecto negativo da trava da execução é que o bipe nunca é tocado enquanto o programa checa o log. Portanto, a duração do bipe deve ser pensada conforme a conveniência - um valor muito alto reduz o tempo de resposta do desligamento, e um valor muito baixo faz com que o bipe fique "piscando" demais, pois este não é tocado durante o laço de leitura do log.